# Dynamic registration of celery tasks

Tags: python, celery

I would like to which is the best way to use celery with tasks registered at runtime. My workfflow is as follows:

- Start celery app
- Start python app
- The python app creates a new task that I would like to schedule in celery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I have accomplished is the based on the "plugin" concept based on the same idea that the [click package has with custom subcommands](http://click.pocoo.org/6/commands/#custom-multi-commands) has.

The app structure (based on python 3):

```
.
├── dynamic_tasks.py
├── run.py
└── tasks
    └── get_rate.py
```

The celery task ***dynamic_tasks.py*** is defined as following:

```
import os
import celery

app = celery.Celery('dynamic_tasks', broker='amqp://guest@192.168.169.1/', backend='rpc://')

PLUGIN_FOLDER = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'tasks')
def _absolutepath(filename):
    """ Return the absolute path to the filename"""
    return os.path.join(PLUGIN_FOLDER, filename)

@app.task
def tasks(funcname, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        funcname = funcname.replace('-', '_')
        funcname += '.py'
        func = _absolutepath(funcname)
        ns = {}
        with open(func) as f:
            code = compile(f.read(), func, 'exec')
            eval(code, ns, ns)
        return ns['task'](*args, **kwargs)
    except IOError as e:
       # Manage IOError
       raise e
```

The plugable task example ***tasks/get_rate.py***:

```
""" This task get the currency rate between a pair of currencies """    
import urllib.request

URL = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s={}=X&f=p'

def task(pair='EURSEK', url_tmplt=URL):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url_tmplt.format(pair)) as res:
        body = res.read()
    return (pair, float(body.strip()))
```

And, simply, to run the example from ***run.py***:

```
from dynamic_tasks import tasks

print(tasks.delay('get_rate', 'EURSEK').get())
```

**EDITED**
Since celery runs on differents machine it is not possible to rely on the local filesystem. My new approach is to send the function to execute as string:

```
@app.task
def dynamic_tasks(funcname, funccode, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        ns = {}
        code = compile(funccode, funcname, 'exec')
        eval(code, ns, ns)
        logger.info('execute %r with args %r, %r', funcname, args, kwargs)
        return ns['task'](*args, **kwargs)
    except IOError:
        logger.error("Error loading the dynamic function from text %s", funcname)
```